# View loggedin windows username in project created using asp.net core angular template

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

how to get current logged in username in Asp.net Core Angular Project, I want to show it in angular view.

Comment: Assuming you want to do this for the client looking at the frontend, this isn't possible. You can't get the details of the windows user using javascript (angular).

Comment: so how to show the current logged in asp.net core angular project ?

Comment: I am looking for a workaround

Comment: Please detail your requirements of the showing info.

Answer (score 0):

> how to get current logged in username in Asp.net Core Angular Project, I want to show it in angular view.

If possible, you can try to create and expose an endpoint for getting user information, like below.

```
[HttpGet("/getusername")]
public JsonResult GetAuthenticatedUserName()
{
    var user = "default";
    if (User!=null)
    {
        user = User.Identity.Name;
    }

    return new JsonResult(user);
}
```

Then you can make an additional request from Angular client side to that endpoint to get your expected data.

```
http.get<string>(baseUrl + 'getusername', { withCredentials: true}).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
  this.authenticatedusername = result;
}, error => console.error(error));
```

Test Result

[image]